# New user signup redirect to tour and most-voted questions

Tags: feature-request, new-users

Could we add "good" example questions (or questions from the "most votes" sort) to [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/about)? Additionally, there is the "tour" button available on the page for new users, but can we automatically redirect new users to one of those two pages upon completing signup? Awarding the "informed" badge is nice incentive, but I wonder if we shouldn't shoehorn new users into the tour or at least the help page (and add examples of "good" questions there) after email verification and before presenting them with the "ask a question" button.

My question stems from an experience I had the other day: One of my friends recently signed up for Stack Overflow with intent to ask a question. He came to me after reading the help page, asking what constitutes "a good question" so that he could model his questions on these examples. He hadn't seen the "tour" button and lamented that it wasn't part of the signup process, or at least an automatic redirect. I had to teach him how to maneuver to the "most votes" sorted questions to give him an idea of what constitutes "good content" on SO. It seems braindead for anybody whom has used the site, but for someone who has never used SO, it appears to be a legitimate concern.

UPDATE: "Most voted" was a placeholder suggestion that could be replaced by any of the various, or even a new one. The central issue here is getting new user eyeballs onto "good" content, not promoting "most voted" content as particularly "good". Please don't interpret this question as suggesting one type of content as "good" over another, but understand that this question is about promoting new users looking at whatever "good" content is defined as.

Comment: Well at least this will be helpful for users that care about their post quality.

Comment: Just curious, did he finally succeed in asking a "good" question? And what was most helpful, the help center or the examples?

Comment: He did ask a pretty good question (and likewise received some good answers), but he is a very intelligent, thoughtful person and I think he wouldn't ask a bad one. I've just asked him in a chat and he says that "the tour was helpful learning the mechanics but the highest voted questions helped most to ... show me how to ask my question well."

Comment: instead of "most-voted", I'd say redirected to some "model" questions, questions that represent what the site is all about. Top voted doesn't necessarily imply "good"

Comment: I would strongly suggest we force new users to the How to Ask a Question pages. The amount of questions we get that shouldn't be here in the first place is ridiculous.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think this is particularly a good idea.

A lot of the "most upvoted" questions contain things that are not very appropriate on Stack Overflow today. Even if we ignore the now offtopic ones, there are collaborative effort questions there.

What about the top monthly questions list?

Comment: Or maybe a mod could pick the best posts?

Comment: See my question update.