# Replace how-to-ask page for new users, with the tour page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, new-users

There are several other questions with a similar spirit, or have THIS VERY FEATURE-REQUEST bundled along with longer, more-complicated suggestions:

[Let's improve the How to Ask page(s)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258251/lets-improve-the-how-to-ask-pages)

[New user signup redirect to tour and most-voted questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258776/new-user-signup-redirect-to-tour-and-most-voted-questions)

[I think we're pointing new users at the wrong "How to Ask" page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253356/i-think-were-pointing-new-users-at-the-wrong-how-to-ask-page)

Unfortunately, this specific (seemingly easy) suggestion seems to have been overlooked. So it's as simple as that:

> Replace this page:
>   
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice
>   
>   
> With this page for new users:
>   
> https://stackoverflow.com/tour

The latter page is visual, and informs would-be users of how the SYSTEM works instead of telling them about principles. With any audience, and I would think *especially* with programmers, talking about SYSTEMS and RULES is a lot more productive than talking about principles.

(The system after all eventually only serves to enforce the principles).

Now consider the first line:

> "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions"

This (and the accompanying image) tells me RIGHT AWAY that SO (or any other SE site) is NOT a forum, and how I'm supposed to use the system. Very simple.

Then there is this line:

> "Get answers to practical, detailed questions"

This tells even the most dense user that vague questions that drone on, are out. Of course, they *could* always think they are being "practical" and "detailed" even when they are posting a discussion-oriented question, but that's what the SYSTEM (of downvotes, flags and closures) is for.

Anybody who *CARES* about behaving well on the site, on the other hand, get a little bit of ACTUALLY useful information about how to post and WHAT to post. For those who want to know more, links to MVCE and other FAQ/blog-posts could also be added.

> The Tour page, by virtue of being visual, concise and PRACTICAL in its scope and advice, seems obviously far more useful than the how-to-ask page actually being shown to new users.

So why not replace the bad one with the good one? As simple as that.

Comment: "...especially with programmers, talking about SYSTEMS and RULES is a lot more productive than talking about principles.." I know the first part of this phrase may be a little controversial. After all to be a good programmer you have to understand the design principles of whichever system you are writing in. However, a LOT of (especially) beginner programmers, the ones most likely to make mistakes using the site, get by using sample code etc, and thus appreciate the kind of documentation that tells them WHAT to do, instead of why to do this.

Comment: This is also true among some more experienced programmers. For example, I've generally seen a lot of hatred online for Apple documentation, and praise for MSDN. I personally don't get it. Code without context (as it happens often on MSDN) and a huge heap of information (as on a manpage or also on MSDN) is extremely confusing to me. I prefer to understand a bit of WHY and what other parts of the framework a specific class interacts with, before getting to the variables/methods a class actually contains. In that I prefer Apple's approach...contd.

Comment: ...contd. But even in putting THIS across, the basic IDEA of the site,  and a quick overview of the principles, I feel the tour page does a FAR better job than the how-to-ask page.

Comment: Shouldn't those comments be part of your question?

Comment: No, it's an addendum, and just expands on the brief points already mentioned in the question. I feel it would distract from the core of the question.

Comment: Then put them at the bottom of your question with a note saying so?

Comment: I'm sorry, but do you feel that the comments add something essential to the question? I do not feel that way - I merely see these as a semi-rant. I have already mentioned in the question that the Tour page is better, conveys more useful information than the how-to-ask page. The comments only provided space for me to rant a little further on the topic. I myself don't see the comments as being ESSENTIAL to the question! :) But if you do, please let me know how.

Comment: In a question that IS about brevity and compactness, it seems contradictory for me to post a slight tangent in the question itself. I understand your point that maybe I am abusing the comment section. Maybe I am - but I'd prefer that to polluting the question, or abusing the question space for posting a tangent. I hope my point of view is clear with this.

Comment: I understand your point. I was just thinking that if you have something to say that would help explain your viewpoint a bit better, it would fit better in a separate section after the main part of your question, especially considering its length. Your question as is doesn't have to be "polluted" -- your semi-rant can live in a separate, disclaimer'd section of the question that readers don't have to read. But it's fine if you wish to leave that in the comments section.

Comment: True. But the purpose of the comments was not so much to illustrate the core viewpoint better, but to preempt anyone who were to feel strongly about the "..talking about SYSTEMS and RULES is a lot more productive.." bit and were to take to the comments section to counter that. :) I have seen several texts (and non-fiction books) that hammer a conceptual point in repeatedly but I personally prefer them stated once and stated clearly. Please don't take this as hubris :) but I'd prefer to use that approach first, and of course if it doesn't work, I'd try the other approach...(contd..)

Comment: ...Also the implicit assumption is that people (who actively use SE) would understand why systems and rules work better than principles , and therefore the comments are only for the (potentially) small percentage who may not. Of course, I could be very wrong about that being a small percentage and in that case a fool for ignoring your advice :) (since it could mean the feature-request could be down-voted out of existence because the point isn't understood) But I'd rather learn by experience sometimes, even if it means a small stumble. Regardless, I do appreciate the helpful input! Thank you.

Comment: Ah OK, makes sense. Sorry for making you write all that to explain yourself!

Comment: No problem! Nitpicking and worrying about intent is one of the key features of SO/SE :)

Answer (score 2):

So... You're right, that page could use a bit of love.

But it has one critical feature that /tour does not:

### Search

[image: yes, search]

A real, live, working search box. *And people **use** it!*

As hard as it can be sometimes to get folks to do any searching before asking a question, this is not something wise to toss aside. Heck, we could probably throw away most of the rest of that page and just keep that search box - but we do want to keep that search!

Comment: "*And people **use** it!*" Oh, you're such a tease.

Comment: Not enough of them, I'm afraid. But hey, always good to remember that things could be worse.

Comment: Hm. What about adding another line about how the system works to the Tour page - "Questions that are duplicates of other questions are CLOSED! Search for your problem before posting" (perhaps a little friendlier text), ALONG with the search box. Seems a little clumsy I know, but if the objective is to make people understand the rules/system and how to use it, this makes sense as being one more step in the learning process. Besides, what about the search/suggestions on the Ask page. Don't people click on the recommendations there? Just asking if you're collecting that data too.