# New user crash-and-burn

Tags: discussion

So, I just witnessed a new user crash and burn pretty hard on his maiden question. Downvotes, close-votes, admonishment via comments, etc. He felt attacked and became pretty agitated.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894856/how-would-i-find-a-button-and-submit-it-on-a-page-i-just-opened-with-window-open
Screenshot:

> [image]

Are comments the place to educate a user about the use of SO? What's the best way to handle something like this after it's already blown up? Is there some kind of special effort we're supposed to make to save this user? What went wrong here, specifically?

Comment: "What's the best way to handle something like this after it's already blown up?" - Ignore the user and walk away. The site gets 7000+ questions a day. Surely there some that are worth your time more than this.

Comment: Looks like a user who can't take constructive criticism. His response to show us the code is "no.". To being told that he doesn't understand SO that the commenter is "very rude". I have little sympathy.

Comment: It's a classic naive newbie post, though a bit better than "here's my codez fix it."   Sure the user feels roughed up, but hey we aren't a daycare center.   I *do* wish that the hard-feelings can be prevented, but saving a major overhaul of ... like *everything* .... things will stay the same

Comment: There are ways to write a constructive comment to such a user - there is no need to shove our standards down their throats (which, as you said, can be counter-productive). Pointing them to the help center with a hint that following the guidelines will help _them_ can do much.

Comment: Nothing is conclusive on that question; the asker can still edit to respond to the comments.

Comment: @Oded: Presumably it was you that wiped the comments? I'd like to suggest restoring the first comments by each of Huangism, canon, and Kevin B. They are strictly about the technical content of the question, and are important suggestions for the asker should e chose to edit.

Comment: `I dont want to provide any code` speaks volumes.  Seems clear he did not read anything presented to him before posting.  I dont feel sorry for him.

Comment: @canon The OP may never come back, but you've done a good deed for the site as a whole by turning crap into diamonds. Well done!

Comment: Stop saving everyone. These are humans, not mountain gorillas. There is no need to save people from themselves, or to hold their hand all the way, spelling for them, typing for them, reading the site policies for them, thinking for them, as you try convert their crap into something good. They will not thank you for it, they will just make a new post with the same crappy quality. And then you have to come save them again. And again. If you want to save the world, there are plenty of better things out there that you could direct your energy towards.

Comment: I personally think we need to be nicer to new users.  How would you feel if it was you asking the question, and perhaps didn't even know about the site tour, etc... I now personally try to hold off on clicking downvote on new users, but politely welcome them to Stack Exchange, and point them in the right direction.

Comment: @Jonathan People *were* being nice to the user.  They were informing him of the problems with his question, and providing him with the resources to fix it.  He responded to the situation with insults and demands that others do what he want regardless of his contributions.  Doing what someone wants and doing all of their work for them even when they post a horrible question and respond extremely unconstructively is not what it means to "be nice".  And not downvoting very poor posts like these is being extremely inconsiderate of all other future readers who will think this isn't a bad question.

Comment: @Jonathan: "didn't even know about the site tour" -- every new asker [is presented with the Help Center's "How to ask" page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84670/), even [including a search box](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265313/).

Comment: Related: [How can other users warn a new user frequently missing the SO policies for how to ask?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272866)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

When the user starts posting unconstructive comments, is clearly not interested in learning how to contribute to the site effectively, and is only causing problems in response to constructive criticisms explaining what is wrong with the question and how to fix it you clearly can no longer help this person.  Flag any inappropriate comments for a mod to clean up and downvote/vote to close the question so that others won't waste their time coming to the question, and just leave.

If the user is responding constructively to the feedback then you're welcome to use comments to help them understand how to improve their question.  That's literally *exactly* what comments are there for.  If you find that the discussion is going on for a lengthy period of time, you may consider moving it to chat in order to have a more interactive feedback loop in the discussion and to avoid cluttering up the main SO question.

Comment: @canon While I think you did a good thing by helping someone out, I fail to see how that question is ever going to be useful for anyone else than the OP. For the `popup.document.$` part I'd be tempted to VTC for **simple typographical error** (I didn't though) and for the waiting for the page to load part, well that's probably a duplicate.

Comment: @canon Maybe "typo" isn't the best word for it, but the essence of that close reason is _this is unlikely to ever help anyone else_. A problem that is so localized to the OPs codebase is unlikely to be found useful by any later visitors. Yes, waiting for the document to load is a common novice error, which is why I am confident there's already several questions/answers concerning it without even having to search. Your answer, which is good, is the only thing stopping me from trying to close the question.

Comment: In fact, I just did a search anyway and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950620/javascript-cross-window-interaction which is basically the same question but with no JQuery involved.

Comment: @canon - the guy just opened another question asking the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915012/why-wont-this-code-work-jquery-javascript-ajax

Comment: @canon And then, another account to ask the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917773/im-not-sure-why-this-isnt-submitting-the-button

Answer (score 13):

What's the best way to handle something like that? Vote to close and downvote?

What has gone wrong? Nothing. It was just another help vampire who wants other people to fix problems for him, but doesn't care even to put enough effort in the question. It looks like it was a kind of chat for him.

In that particular case I can't see how anything could go better. The user still didn't learned anything, no answer is accepted, no positive feedback, asking new questions in comments to someone's answer... Maybe the question ban will learn him something... or at least there will be one help vampire less...

Answer (score 5):

Comments are the best place to educate a user. If their question is poor, then they'll attract downvotes. A comment to say as much - and offer a link to something useful like "How to ask" - gives the opportunity to understand *why* they're crashing and burning. And ideally - to fix it.

It's courteous when seeking assistance (especially free) to have a look at how a site operates, and understand what's expected.

Whilst that's something that's fairly often lacking, that doesn't mean it should be allowed to pass - if you reward bad behavior you get more bad behavior. That's not to say it's a fatal error though - not by any means - I don't think there's many people here who hold a grudge for a poor newbie question. Coming back and asking again, following the clear guidance as to the etiquette expected will yield positive results.

Although in this case - like plenty of others - creating an MCVE might have revealed the error, and meant no question in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

There are people who will not ever, under any circumstance, think to read the rules before posting. Even if you tell them to stop and go read the rules, they will avoid doing so at all costs, because reading rules is boring and they do not have the capacity to endure a little boring work for the sake of the greater good. It's a reality, and it's pretty common behavior; if it weren't, we wouldn't need rules. We wouldn't need an SO, and we certainly wouldn't have a MetaSO.

There is no way to make him follow rules, or want to, and there's little value in keeping him around. SO is not an environment where this user will thrive. Let him go find somewhere that is better aligned to his personality.

Comment: _"...if it weren't, we wouldn't need rules."_ No, we'd still need the rules. We'd just not need comments telling people to go read the rules, or links to the rules in the close reasons. :) If we had no rules because everyone read the rules, then there would be nothing for anyone to read and it would be "anything goes."

Comment: It's not exactly for their greater good, because poor questions often still get answered.