# Is ambiguity in the current voting system having a chilling effect on learning?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting

### The Good

Over at Stack Overflow, [I asked a question about implementing an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876500/tail-recursive-factorial-in-fortran95).

The first answer did not address the question, but rather the attempted solution. After finding my own solution, I was compelled to use my solution to address the actual question. I did this while maintaining the prospect of having my solution critiqued by people more knowledgeable on the subject than I.

As was hoped for, my proposed solution did provide the necessary fodder for a brief discussion, and ultimately modifications to the first contributor's answer. The first contributors new answer was then accepted.

All together: the original question, the first answer, my prospective solution, and the accepted answer do complement each other to provide a complete and valuable learning experience for people attempting to become familiar with the respective topic.

### The Bad

As I am not interested in participating in the accumulation of superfluous virtual trinkets, I was not compelled to hold back my prospective (and retrospectively inferior) solution to the problem. This decision has benefited me well with the accumulation of valuable knowledge, despite exposing myself to "reputation-al" punishment.

As currently implemented, voting on my prospective answer is meaningless.

- Does one downvote my prospective answer because they are against its neglect for subjective qualities such as "best practices"?
- Does one upvote my proposed solution because they feel it correctly answered the question being asked at a time when no other answer did as such?
- Does one upvote my proposed solution because they feel it complements the question and the accepted answer so as to provide a complete learning experience?
- If one does downvote my proposed solution for not following the best practices (which were only later added to the accepted answer), how does that not flag to future readers that the information contained within should be ignored rather than taken as complementary to the accepted answer?
- If one does upvote my proposed solution, how does that endorsement not result in hand-waiving with respect to the points brought up in the accepted answer?

I cannot simply delete my prospective answer now, as it has become tightly coupled to the rest of the question/answer content.

### The Ugly

Despite my indifference to Stack Exchange's virtual trinket system, I realize that I am more likely an outlier in this community. Personally, I fail to grasp how a person motivated by "points" and "badges" would ever be compelled to stick their neck out and offer their inferior solutions to complicated problems. When the ambiguous voting system serves no other purpose for these people than the enforcement of broad educational abstinence under any uncertainty, knowledge gets punished and everybody loses.

### Proposed Solution

Rather than using an overly simplified and purely homogenized metric for measuring the usefulness of information (upvote/downvote), I propose that Stack Exchange take steps to heterogenize the way in which users rank and score contributions of knowledge.

I further propose that since knowledge is an evolutionary process, ranking and scoring should also be able to consider context of content: e.g. "Has the answer become obsolete in the face of a new answer?".

At the end of the day, these improved and heterogeneous metrics shall each inflict their own (independently weighted) influence on the scalar "points" and "badges" of users. At the same time, making knowledge content more meaningful and potentially easing the pressure on trinket accumulators who may currently be coerced into silence.

**Remark**

*Good faithed contributions which become obsolete after influencing later contributions should not justify the punishment of trinket seeking users who contributed the best of knowledge from an earlier era.*

**Remark**

I fully anticipate that members of Stack Exchange will scoff at my concerns as baseless. However, how do you explain the observation of users devoting meaningful quantities of their life contributing valuable knowledge to this network on the premise that they shall obtainin **zero tangible beneift** for their time?

**Remark**

I am not advocating for naively increasing the difficulty in realizing a decline of ones "points" and "badges". Plain "point"/"badge" dilution would not accomplish anything. Instead, I expect that any scalarizing function used to compute "points"/"badges" from these new metrics shall consequentially increase the relative meaningfulness of such trinkets.

Comment: Related: [Downvotes on Meta are confusing: do they *really* mean poor-post quality, or just disagreement?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254108/456814). Ambiguity in the "*overly simplified and purely homogenized metric for measuring the usefulness of information*" exists on Meta as well.

Comment: Is it "The Good, The Bad & The Ugly" day? Related in a loose sense: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361

Comment: "Personally, I fail to grasp how a person motivated by "points" and "badges" would ever be compelled to stick their neck out and offer their inferior solutions to complicated problems." --> Because some of us are motivated by a desire to help people, rep be damned.

Comment: I wouldn't really draw conclusions on perceived voting trends from a question that has only been seen 50 times (some of which quite possibly coming from the 20 views on this Meta question), with only 2 votes on the question and 2 votes on one of the two answers. (All of that when having been a member for only 2 days...)

Comment: Forgive me if I am not enlightened enough to understand your question, but to be honest your question seems a little like you place too much emphasis on the voting system. Votes aren't supposed to be the be-all-and-end-all judgement of an answer, and were never supposed to take that role. In addition, your pontificating is making your question somewhat convoluted. Just state your proposal (add additional ways to rank answers besides just votes) and the reasoning (people are scared of being downvoted, and hence don't answer), as well as proof, and leave it at that.

Comment: Seriously. Congratulations on your immense grasp of the English language, but if you want to get your point across efficiently and effectively... Well, there's an art in simplicity. You're not writing a speech for a head of state here.

Comment: @user3580294 Please accept my apologies for having aspergers syndrome. Is there anything you would like to add to the topic of down-vote aversion?

Comment: My apologies then for any undue criticism; rather harsh judgement on my part. For that particular topic, there isn't really a whole lot you can do; as long as you allow downvotes in some shape or form, then someone's going to be scared off at some point. I have to ask, though; Do you have any evidence for the claim that downvote aversion is preventing people from answering with *good* answers? I would imagine that if someone believe their answer to be right, he/she will post it, and if he/she isn't sure, he/she will leave a comment, and if the answer is wrong, then the downvotes are deserved.

Answer (score 12):

Rather than address hypothetical voting scenarios, why not evaluate what actually happened?

1. No downvotes on question.  So far so good.
2. No downvotes on accepted answer.  Still good.
3. No downvotes on your answer.  We good?

Here's the real win: not only did you get a good, informative answer to your question, but you also got valuable feedback on the answer you posted, without being overly penalized.

Verdict:

## \o/

The real heroes of Stack Overflow are not seeking trinkets as their primary motivation; they are looking to help people, exercise their knowledge, and maybe get a few unicorn points as a pleasant bonus.

Comment: If eliminating reputation metrics all together would have no impact on contributions (as you hypothesize) wouldn't it be in Stack Exchanges operational interest to remove that futile overhead?

I think that unicorn point accumulation is motivating people to contribute. Consequently, I also think that the threat of unicorn point decline simultaneously compels users to abstain from contributing when they are not 100% confident. For anecdotal evidence, [see the comments from a quick google search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836852/bizarre-result-taking-the-logical-not-of-an-xor)

Comment: *"If eliminating reputation metrics all together would have no impact on contributions"* -- Nice try, but I never said that. :)  I've added a small clarification to my answer.

Comment: What is that link supposed to be evidence of @user0xf00?

Comment: @Bart the comments in link shows that there exists SOME users who exhibit aversion to being downvoted.

Comment: @Bart [Here is another](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660653/what-is-the-relationship-between-multicollinearity-and-standard-error)

Comment: Breaking news: People prefer pat on back over being told they are wrong or incorrect. Doesn't mean we shouldn't tell them, nor that telling them causes harm.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Perhaps instead of reading too much into the example I have provided, you could ellaborate on efforts by Stack Exchange to study and mitigate down-vote aversion?

Comment: "*I also think that the threat of unicorn point decline simultaneously compels users to abstain from contributing when they are not 100% confident.*" It's not about confidence, it's about telling people off when they say something incorrect. In the world, there seems to be no shortage of people who talk non-sense about stuff they really know nothing about. Here, people who are not 100% confident can attempt to answer, but if they're wrong they shouldn't be surprised to get a downvote, rather they should check for a better solution; if they get an upvote that's even better. Win-win both ways.