# Is it OK to downvote or close new users' first questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, downvotes, new-users

I have seen new users asking questions that are vague, duplicate or have other problems. However, is it OK to expect them to be adapted to Stack Overflow on day one? We learned with time.

Besides new users also face rude comments on their questions. Shouldn't newbies be encouraged and taught in some better way?

Comment: Rude comments should be avoided and flagged if applicable. Having said that, politely ask them to go through the 'tour' and 'help center pages' to learn about the norms and guidelines related to the site. We expect that new users will put in efforts to learn how the site works and what is expected from them before they start using the site. Stack Exchange team (with community's help) has put in considerable effort in building the Help Center pages. New users should read them first.

Comment: "Stack Forum" - This isn't a forum.

Comment: Unfortunately, the group of first time posters will always have the highest ratio of ignorant and careless people. This is one reason why there exists a review queue for all first time posts. The people doing first post reviews are encouraged to leave a comment to posts with problems, explaining how the post can be improved.

Comment: Every single user was new someday. We are proof that new users _can_ learn and survive, _if_ they read the rules. Flag all rude comments, that's the best way to help new users. Most of the flags get handled without mods because rude comments have typical keywords.

Comment: I've tried to look at solutions to help educate new users, namely: [Could some bad questions be avoided with additional prompting?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting) and [The Good, The Bad & The Ugly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly). The hope is that some users may get a better first experience if they had a little more help up front that wasn't simply a long page of text.

Comment: The answers below are absolutely correct, and thanks for wanting to know more about the topic!

Comment: Related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs

Comment: How can they learn without us telling them where they are wrong?

Comment: If we keep question editing and commenting first priority

Comment: Well, I don’t expect them to “adapt Stack Overflow” instantaneous but yes, I expect them “on day one”. I usually leave a comment (if others didn’t yet) so usually a bad question receives constructive criticism *within minutes*. If the question is still as low quality *after hours*, well, downvote, close, delete…

Comment: Has no one thought of perhaps doing some kind of "test" before posting a question/answer? eg. Show examples of answers/questions (depending on what the user wants to post) and have them decide if they are **good** or **bad**, see if their decision is correct according to stackoverflow? It could be done if you use examples pulled from the archives couldn't it?

Comment: "*However, is it OK to expect them to adapt Stack Overflow on day one? We learned with time.*" [BoltClock](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2275202#2275202): "*I feel so left out. I 'got' Stack Overflow from day one and I had absolutely no trouble following the rules to the letter.*" Stack Overflow's rules follow a lot of just plain common sense, as well as software industry conventions and culture. A lot of people ought to "just get it", yes, on Day One.

Comment: Oh, (atm) 13 downvotes for this question. Why?

Comment: @Cupcake I think you're way overestimating the ease of adapting to a 'culture', especially one who comes from 'cultures' that are quite different. Or maybe you just don't think of all the rules there really are. Don't greet people in your post, don't use friendly niceties, understand the formatting syntax for your post, don't answer questions only with a link, don't ask too many questions in one post, don't ask too dumb of a question in a post, understand that some questions that would help people and used to be okay might not be okay anymore for various reasons...

Comment: I literally could fill up multiple more comments with things that you expect someone to 'just get'. It's not realistic. Yes, it's fine that SO has rules and expects users to follow them, but new users who don't understand should be dealt with with grace and tact, not with a crazy expectation of 'getting it'

Comment: @JKillian again, I have to point out, a lot of those "rules" are just plain common sense things that you would do if you want to write a clear, understandable message to other people through digital media. At least, if you ever took a writing class in high school in a Western country, you ought to already have an idea of how to do this. As for the "no greetings and thanks" rules, those are all things that come from discussion forum culture, which the [se] sites are certainly not, and are easily fixed through a simple edit to remove them.

Comment: @Cupcake Fair enough. However, the rules regarding what is and is not a legitimate question to ask are specifically hard to grasp, even more so if English isn't your first language I'm guessing. This is mainly where new users have issues. I understand that the help center tries to go over this thoroughly, but that doesn't mean it's easy to understand. And I think it's fine to point out these issues to new users, but I don't think the attitude that they should just intrinsically get it helps.

Comment: ["Don't handicap your children by making their lives easy."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268147/839601)

Comment: I see very few rude comments directed at new users. I suspect you consider any critical comment to be rude. I see plenty of critical comments directed at new users who *deserve* them.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Flagging/close voting for content problems is always appropriate for a question that is off-topic, too vague etc, whether the user is a first posting newbie or a five year SO veteran.

Same for downvoting - although I personally tend to give new users a bit more leeway, especially for questions that show at least an attempt at being good. I leave a comment with a flag, and downvote if the question is particularly bad.

Once another user chastized downvoters of a poor, perennial duplicate question that had a +1/-5 vote score, saying that we should welcome new users and show them how the site works. I think the opposite is true: to properly welcome newbies, you need to give them the feedback they need, along with downvotes if they truly deserve them - and upvotes if they earn them. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Isn't it better to teach through meaningful comments only. Down votes and closed questions are depressing and unfriendly I fell.

Comment: @XIMRX, that's why, like I said, I tend to give newbies leeway before voting down a question. Give them a chance to fix their question.

Comment: @XIMRX: if we leave bad questions open, the site suffers, people will stop using it, and newbies won't get good answers to their good questions, either. If you want to see the logical conclusion to this process, just visit Yahoo Answers.

Comment: Yes. Flagging isn't a huge deal to the asked: questions on hold can still be improved and reopened.

Comment: @All of the above: in case you [gain >3000 rep](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3154/how-should-my-flagging-change-when-i-gain-the-ability-to-vote-to-close), **flagging** is actually the wrong word here. [Flagging a post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) should be used for *serious* problems. If you can, use [Downvoting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) to indicate your personal disapproval, and [Close votes](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) for questions that are likely not salvegable.

Comment: @Jongware, oh yes, I'll note that in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Jongware Closevoting is for serious problems, not "unsalvageable". If there isn't enough code in the question, I'm going to close it as such, not wait for OP to get his act together. The first revision should be perfect, and if it isn't CVs and DVs will come.

Comment: Indeed -- closed questions can (and should) be re-opened after the problems that led to their closure are solved.

Comment: I personally agree with this answer as it advocates newbies leeway to some extent. But unfortunately votes are saying no leeway.

Comment: @XIMRX: That's the difference between a tutoring site, or a site with low traffic at least, and a serious Q&A site.

Answer (score 158):

## Yes.

It's perfectly fine to vote down/close/flag new user's first question. And you should do so if the question deserves it.

If it was my first time playing in a basketball game, should I not be given a technical foul for punching someone in the face? Rules have to be followed regardless of the players/users experience.

I do agree that rude comments aren't the most helpful.

Learning is often the result of making a mistake! For example, I didn't clean my room, and got a punishment for it. So now, I know that I should clean my room or face punishment. If we let the first question of a new user slide, then they'll think it's OK to ask these bad questions for their 2nd question. So you're just delaying the inevitable.

Comment: Thanks iStimple indeed it is `delaying the inevitable`

Comment: @AndrewBarber whenever I read a very low quality question, I feel as bad as if I had been punched in the face. So my count would total +3 for iStimple, but the only upvote I can leave here will have to do.

Comment: @Renan -1 for the personal foul. +2 for giving me two free throws! = +1

Comment: Votes saying this is the answer. But `no mercy` should not be the accepted answer. There should be slight lenience.

Comment: @XIMRX No, there really shouldn't. Lenience doesn't scale. Too many new users, too many crap questions. The sooner new users become aware of the way things are done here, the better.

Comment: don't think basketball game is a good example. Punching someone in the face, you directly hurt him. But newbie with new one question doesn't hurt anyone. and downvote him just make him has a bad feeling when first see the site.

Comment: -1 for basketball analogy. The first time I played basketball (in a mandatory gym class) nothing was mentioned but the most basic of rules. They never did teach me anything about playing well, even after years of basketball in gym class.

Comment: Bet you got punished a lot...

Comment: -1 for relying on the [Straw Man falacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) in your analogy of "punching someone in the face".

Comment: Wouldn't it be more like someone *accidentally traveling with a basketball?*

Comment: @Compass: We see first posts like that too.  But some are of the punch-to-the-face level of incivility.

Comment: An old question but just came across an example where new user posted a question, checked in 8 hours later and saw a -2 score, and never logged in again. I agree with XIMRX, **_no mercy should NOT be the answer_** to this question!

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it is reasonable to expect new users to follow the rules from the very start. Just like all other communities. Where you live, are new car drivers allowed to exceed the speed limit? There are many first posts from SO users that have been up voted, favourited and have many views, so it is entirely possible to follow the rules from the start.

The rules are clear enough, and unavoidably presented. New users who break them have decided that *they* don't need to bother studying the rules, or take care to write a good post. It is **they** who are being rude.

Comment: Where I live, experienced drivers routinely exceed the speed limit.

Answer (score 7):

Stack Overflow has come to a point where a developer not knowing about it is as absurd as a regular person not knowing about Facebook or Google.

That said, I understand that societies nowadays tolerate more and more people who do not <strike>RTFM</strike> take the time to read some quick, introductory guide on how to use a system (i.e.: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I see a growing number of comments in meta about how we can't expect new users to read through the help center.

However... It doesn't cost you an arm to read through some questions before asking, you know. It takes five minutes to skim through SO and read a handful of questions, and notice that a certain quality standard is expected from a post.

If a prospective user has skipped the help center and hasn't taken the time to see how the site works before posting for the first time, and posts a low quality question... They had it coming when the question is downvoted and closed.

I believe that any first questions should not show up in main pages until they have been reviewed in the queue. I would love a rule where everyone with a reputation below 100 would only have their questions showing up at all at the root site or in /questions after passing through review. They could have all the feedback they need to learn how to post there.

Comment: It's been a year and then some - when registering, aren't you invited to *take the Tour*? The one that earns your very first badge, "Informed"? It's the first thing I check on a new-user's Very First Question.

Comment: @Jongware Yup. The tour is linked. Help center articles are linked everywhere. You have to scroll and click thru a "how-to ask" page to post your first question.

Answer (score 0):

One counterargument to the simple "yes, it helps them learn": downvoting alone doesn't help people learn, at least not efficiently.  The space of "bad questions" is enormous, and if a new user is asking a question you don't think is good, it probably means that they don't know how to ask a good one.

Downvoting as a part of teaching new users makes total sense, but the approach of issuing a drive-by downvote with no further explanation is discouraging without really helping to educate the user.

Comment: If you mean just piling on with "drive-by downvoting", well, that would not be good. But if one takes the time to determine for oneself whether it deserves a downvote, that is good and neccessary for separating the chaff from the grain. Of cource, adding a comment directing the poster in the right direction for improving his question (if he seems receptive and one has something to add) is always good, for any post.

Comment: That's actually an aspect I didn't consider - what I meant was that a downvote with no explanation is unlikely to help a new user working out what was wrong with their post.  As for simply helping other users differentiate which posts are worth checking on, that's a useful step that didn't occur to me.

Answer (score -16):

In most cases a close vote is more appropriate than a downvote.

1. Close votes are required to have a reason.  It is the *reason* that will help the user ask a better question.
2. A downvote means "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".  This assessment is subjective, but I believe that most new users' questions show *some* research effort.

Remember, we want new users to return, and ask their question in a better way.  I hypothesize that a downvote is more discouraging than a close vote.

Comment: A close vote has a generic reason and may not help the user with why the question got closed. Also you are always free to leave comment explaining why you down-voted the question.

Comment: "you are always free to leave comment explaining why you down-voted the question." but most people don't, as the seven downvotes on this answer demonstrate.

Comment: I found the downvotes with no comments here discouraging, and will be less likely to participate in meta in the future.  Just sayin'

Comment: Down votes here just mean they disagree with you as most answers are saying yes

Comment: Oh, I thought downvotes here meant "Not Useful", as that is what the tooltip says.

Comment: On meta it is different and votes are more for agreement and disagreement, it is something people commonly get confused about

Comment: Hmm.  Thanks, that is confusing.  Maybe they should update the tooltip text?