# Is it OK to downvote new users answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, new-users

My question was sparked from reading this fine post: [Is it OK to downvote or close new users' first questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268006/is-it-fine-to-vote-down-mark-too-broad-or-put-on-hold-and-close-new-users-firs)

I've been reading the site for ages, obviously because every attempt at solving a problem by googling it, usually turns up an SO article within the first 5 results.

So I kept finding some good response to legit questions here, but often the "right" answer (the most elegant solution) had fewer upvotes and was not marked as an answer.

So I decided to join and participate hoping I could help improve answers and solutions. This however requires something of an effort. The path I chose seems to be the one most new users choose. We pick the new easy questions, with total disregard to quality, duplication and so on. But after a few days you get enough reputation to actually participate.

So this is what I do. I read a question that has a few fast and desperate untested answers that simply don't work, or they are writing duplicate code or just plain inefficient or unnecessary use of jQuery or whatever.

I honest to god want to help people find the right, "best practice" and efficient solution. Shouldn't I be entitled to spend my reputation downvoting things I find horrible inefficient code?

New users go apeshit in the comments with "EXPLAING TEH DOWNVOTE PLIX!"

Am I wrong to downvote answers for any of the above reasons?

Comment: Not again one of these questions. New users are not special, they can and should be hit with downvotes just like any other user. The only thing that matters is the quality of the post: if it is subpar then you act accordingly.

Comment: This question rambles on a lot and doesn't get to a point clearly enough, consider editing it to be a a clearer, more succinct question.

Answer (score 18):

> Shouldn't I be entitled to spend my reputation downvoting things i find horrible inefficient code?

Sure you are. You can vote as you wish. We hope people vote on the merits of the post - if you find an answer to be bad, downvote away.

Don't vote because of the person who posted or as "strategic" voting (just so your post goes up).

> Am i wrong to downvote answers any of the above reasons?

Not in my opinion.

---

That a user is new should have nothing to do with their posts - if they are bad, they should get downvoted. If they are good, they should be upvoted.

Comment: I don't mind voting up if there's already a great answer, i don't want to readd my answer. But if I find several bad answers and no good ones i feel obligated to provide my own *and* downvote the others. I'm not trying to strategically heighten my post even though it probably looks that way.

Comment: I can only reiterate - you can vote whichever way you want. We hope that you only vote on the merits (or lack thereof) of the posts.

Answer (score 12):

Up vote what you want the site to become.

Down vote what you don't want it to become.

If the question or answer isn't indicative of the quality you wish to see on the site, down vote it.

The familiarity of the user with the norms of the site may be taken into account when explaining a vote, but there are reasons why explaining a vote isn't mandatory (that lead you off into the great rabbit hole of [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/213963) and [all its linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/135?lq=1).

*Not* down voting because a user is new reminds me of a Heinlein quote:

> Don't handicap your children by making their lives easy.

If you don't show what is expected *now* you are tacitly saying that "this is ok" for the quality of the new user going forward.  This leads to... well... crap... when the user thinks "hey, its ok to just dump a link in the text box as an answer and go" and then finds a rude awakening when people who don't down vote "new users" start down voting users that have a few hundred rep.

Comment: I agree with both answers but one difference for me is that if it's a new user and they post a code or link-only answer (I typically dv right away and comment) I will comment and explain the problem. If they don't correct it then I dv. But I like to give them a chance to correct it. For the most part, I think I get good responses from it.

Comment: @codeMagic I've had conversations with users in chat who, after working through how to make a question (in this case better) acknowledge that just a comment wouldn't have prompted them to fix it - it was the down vote that made them *want* to fix the question ([related chat bit](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13900826#13900826)).  Waiting to down vote later also distances the "I wrote crap" from "I got a down vote" relationship in one's mind.

Comment: I see your point about distancing but I don't give it much time. And we can't very well go off of what **one** user said in chat. Also, I have noticed that when I leave a comment indicating the problem then they don't respond well or change it, I downvote and I see others follow. But, if they are new and you just give a downvote, then it can kind of have a "bad stink", IMO. I just like to give them the chance to correct it first.