# Can the question asking page be improved with a reminder about MCVE?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users

One of the most common problems in my experience, especially from new askers, is that they don't fully provide the complete picture such as:

1. Posting only the couple of lines of code that caused the problem.
2. Describing the problem *only in words* without any sort of code.
3. Posting a wall of code except the part where the problem actually lies (this is common in C and C++ because there may be multiple source files involved).
   etc.

These sort of questions make them unanswerable/speculative answers etc. As a result, link to [MCVE] becomes the common comment to questions from new/inexperienced (in SO) users.

While it's great to that we already have a link [MCVE] that can be easily copy-pasted (and a whole [lot of info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on asking questions), it'd be nice to tell the users about [MCVE] *before* they post the questions. Posting [MCVE] comments *after* a question has been asked is a bit late and wastes the time of others (by means of asking clarification, guesswork, downvotes, close votes, etc.).

My question is:

Can the ["Ask a Question" page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) be modified/improved (I don't know exactly how) to remind [MCVE] to new/inexperienced users such as background text reminding them of MCVE or prompting a pop-up or the updating the text in the right-hand "How to Ask" panel or any other way that encourages new users to provide [MCVE] if it's possible for their question(s) to do so.

While I understand there's no guarantee that this will improve the quality of questions dramatically, if it helps a little, *only a little*, it would save most of us a lot of time.

Comment: Not all questions require a mcve.  Heck questions do not even require code.  Not sure if we want to blast mcve to everyone even when they do not need one.

Comment: "We plan to test a new, 'guided' version of the ask question page soon. This page would essentially break down all of the elements that make a great question, and give the user plenty of guidance as to why it's to their advantage to understand what's needed in each of them, and provide it." - from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project

Comment: @NathanOliver That's why I qualified my question with "if it's possible for their question(s) to do so" and phrased as "reminding them" rather than required/necessary (or similar).

Comment: @Oded Glad it's been already discussed in a much broader scope that what I raised here. So, this question is essentially a duplicate as it's covered as a whole for Stack Exchange? (i.e. shall I close this?).

Comment: Doesn't hurt to have it here, always a good discussion to have :)

Comment: @NathanOliver I prefer having it when it's not necessary, than not having it. More information tend to be marginally better than less.

Comment: *If it helps only a little* I don't understand how if it "helps only a little" that would "save most of us a lot of time". I think it would "save most of us a **little** time". I think you're grossly overestimating the capacity of new/inexperienced users to read and process information that is presented to them. Many of the questions themselves are a result of them not being able to read and process information already on the web or found in documentation--why would information about how to ask questions presented in the asking page be any different?

Comment: @torazaburo but we want to be *nice* to new users!

Comment: some related reading: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly