# StackOverflow has a problem with the way they welcome new users

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, new-users, welcoming

I keep seeing all these low-quality, unresearched posts on SO. And a large majority of them are from 5 reputation and lower. Eventually these new users learn but not after taking a beating of criticism. SO's system for helping new users ask question isn't very efficient, they give some tips but those tips aren't very explanatory. A better way to do it would be to give a reputation restriction or/and add more in depth tips. And the reputation restriction would be to let these new users look around the site and see what a good question is like and the explanatory tips would make sure the user gets the full idea. I don't see why SO isn't implementing something like this.

Comment: "And a large majority of them are from 5 reputation and lower." This is a red herring.  The *large* majority of *all* questions are asked by people with 5 rep or less, so obviously the majority of bad questions are asked by people with 5 rep or less.  The likelihood that a given question will be bad is still very high with higher reputation users.  In my experiences, it's generally *higher*.  There are simply very few questions from users with lots of rep *in general*.

Comment: *add more in depth tips.* what should those tips be and where should those be shown?

Comment: Interesting. Part of this reminds me of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266361/5764553 It may be worth replacing (or supplementing) the wizard with something along this line, some day.

Comment: See top answer on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project

Comment: Some high(er) reputation users still open very bad questions, keep answering questions that should be closed, etc. etc. I even regularly see what I consider *very high* rep users (over 100K) that vote to close questions **and** answer it...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

New users get to use the "Ask Question Wizard":

[The Ask Question Wizard is Live!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> If you are under the reputation threshold (currently 111, because that's what we tested with in previous experiments), you will automatically be directed to the wizard, also known as **guided mode**. If you are over that threshold, you'll be taken to the original question asking page, which we're calling **traditional mode**.

Comment: Hard to measure but personally I don't think the mighty wizard has had a significant effect on human nature to either not read or just plain ignore instructions and level of garbage doesn't seem to have changed a lot. Had higher hopes for it's success when it was rolled out.

Comment: @charlietfl you probably hit the nail on the head with the human nature reference - modern human nature, I would say. It's not so much that people are going out of their way to do the wrong things... they're just doing what they want to do. Good luck to convince people, in an online environment, to stop doing what they want to do and do what a laundry list of do's and don'ts wants them to do.

Comment: @charlietfl  But if someone doesn't want to follow the wizard and then posts a crappy answer directly because they didn't follow the guidelines, then the blame falls pretty  squarely on the user, and not SO.

Comment: @opa Wasn't advocating for removing the wizard. It was merely an observation. Not sure what your point is

Comment: @charlietfl I wasn't saying you were?  Answer is "the wizard", you say "wizard doesn't solve the problem".  I'm saying "its the users fault that they ignore the wizard doesn't help them, so it is still a valid answer to the original question, even if it doesn't solve 'human nature'".